# Shift a long equation leftward

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

How to shift a long equation leftward by 20 mm in an article or in revtex4 that cannot fit into a wide page?

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{revtex4}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Blabla}
\lipsum[1]
Under now circumstances use \verb|\hspace|
\begin{eqnarray} 
\hspace*{-4cm}
&&\exp(i(1010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101)) \\
&&\exp(i(1010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101)) 
\end{eqnarray}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

I tried to use \kern-20mm and \hspace*{-20mm} but it has no effect. Any idea on shifting a long equation leftward?

**One issue is that  \hspace*{} seems not working when there are multilines in eqnarray.**

Thank you to the experts here.

[image]

Comment: you should consider to break equation to more rows

Comment: You shouldn't use  eqnarray`. Use `align` instead for a correct spacing.

Comment: Is "`1010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101`" just meant to be an example of some long expression, or are you really trying to display this particular number?

Comment: Please read your equation aloud! can you?

Comment: Thanks -- it just an example of the long equation. **The main issue is that  \hspace*{} seems not working when there are multilines in eqnarray.**

Comment: at least part of the space on the left is caused by the presence of `&&` at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot confirm that `\hspace*` does not work. If you compile

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{revtex4}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Blabla}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{eqnarray} 
\exp(i(1010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101)) 
\end{eqnarray}
Under now circumstances use \verb|\hspace|
\begin{eqnarray} 
\hspace*{-2cm}\exp(i(1010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101)) 
\end{eqnarray}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
Rather, use \verb|widetext|,
\begin{widetext}
\begin{eqnarray} 
\exp(i(1010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101)) 
\end{eqnarray}
\end{widetext}
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

which shows that `\hspace*` works but should not be used. Use `widetext` instead and/or, as @Zarko recommends, try to massage the equation.

Comment: from your answer is clearly that moving equation to the left is not a solution ...  a solution is breaking equation in  more rows (as i pointed in my comment)

Comment: @Zarko I agree and made this more explicit in a revision of my post.

Comment: +1, That works partially, thanks a lot, but **The main issue is that  \hspace*{} seems not working when there are multilines in eqnarray.** If that can work in multilines, your answer is accepted!

Comment: The second example you gave is very desirable.

Comment: @wonderich Well, I get also `\hspace` to work in an equation with several lines, e.g. ` \begin{align}
 &\exp(i(1010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101)) \\
 &\hspace*{-1cm}\exp(i(2020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202))\\
 &\exp(i(3030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303))
 \end{align}`. Could you please check? In any case, it is probably always good to avoid this.

Comment: But it seems not working for \begin{eqnarray}  .. \end{eqnarray}, why is that?

Comment: @wonderich -- `eqnarray` is not particularly well designed for math.  that is one reason that `amsmath` was developed.